# Conteo erróneo usando COUNT(DISTINCT columna) haciendo JOIN con varias tablas

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

Hola a todos y gracias por prestar atención. Estoy aprendiendo SQL Developer y me he encontrado con el siguiente problema:

Debo crear una función para contar la cantidad de nacionalidades de las personas contenidas en una tabla. El asunto es que la única manera de unir las nacionalidades con las personas es a través de su comuna de origen.

- La tabla `PERSONA` se asocia a la tabla `COMUNAS`,
- La tabla `COMUNAS` se asocia a la tabla `REGIONES`,
- y por último la tabla `REGIONES` a la tabla `PAISES`.

Una muestra sería así

Personas

[image: TABLA PERSONAS]

Comunas

[image: TABLA COMUNAS]

Regiones

[image: TABLA REGIONES]

PAISES

[image: TABLA PAISES]

Hasta el momento he intentado con los siguiente...

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_paises RETURN NUMBER IS
        v_cantidad NUMBER;
    BEGIN
        SELECT
            COUNT(DISTINCT pa.id_pais)
        INTO v_cantidad
        FROM
            paises     pa
            JOIN regiones   r ON pa.id_pais = r.id_pais
            JOIN comunas    c ON r.id_region = c.id_region
            JOIN personas   pe ON c.id_comuna = pe.comuna;
        RETURN v_cantidad;
    END;
    /

BEGIN
    dbms_output.put_line(fn_paises);
END;
/
```

Sé que en total debe dar 4, ya que son solo 4 los países en la base de datos. También verifiqué que las comunas asociadas en la tabla personas sean de 4 países diferentes, pero la función que hice solo da como resultado 2.

Les agradezco de antemano, y lo siento por el largo del post...

Comment: No veo nada raro en tu consulta. Tienes 4 países, pero ¿estás seguro que tienes personas de lo 4 países? la forma más sencilla de verificarlo, es hacer la consulta sin el count y ver efectivamente los datos y ver que país falta.

Comment: ¿Qué te devuelve si, fuera de la función, ejecutas el `select distinct` (sin `count()`).?

Comment: @PatricioMoracho gracias por tu respuesta. Llevo haciendo eso que me dices desde antes de ayer y la verdad no me cabía en la cabeza el porqué no me daba el resultado. Sin embargo, lo volví hacer y gracias a eso me dí cuenta de cual era el problema. Empecé a seguir el código de comuna de una persona hasta la tabla regiones y la comuna no se correlacionaba con la región. Las tablas que me enviaron tienen su registro desordenado. 
Bueno, aunque me ayudaste indirectamente con la respuesta me sirvió para asegurarme que lo que hacía estaba correcto.
Gracias otra vez Patricio!

Comment: @jachguate, tenía el mismo resultado, que no estaba mal. Era la correlación entre comunas y regiones donde estaba el desmadre xD

Answer (score 0):

El total sería 4 *si* tienes data para los 4 países en personas. Probablemente tienes solo para 2 países, ya que estás haciendo (inner) joins. También quieres que te salgan los países que *no* tienen personas? Entonces tienes que hacer `left outher join` (por el orden de las tablas en el join) en vez de un simple join para que las tablas hacia la izquierda que no tengan data asociada a la derecha salgan con valores null. En todo caso, cuando hayas resuelto eso, una vez que retomes el problema original que es indicar la cantidad de personas por paises tienes que hacer unos ajustes

```
select p.id, p.nombre, count(*)
from
    blahblah blah # todo lo que ya tienes
    .
    .
group by
    p.id
```

Comment: Gracias por responder @eftshift0, pero como mencioné anteriormente, verifiqué que el contenido de la tabla me diera para 4 países Es un registro de más de 100 personas, por lo mismo, todos las personas tienen alguno de los 4 países.
Y solo necesito que me de resultado un número. Si me dices que lo que hice debería darme el resultado, la verdad ya no sé que pensar jajajaja 
Llevo 3 días con esto y ahora me doy cuenta lo frustrante que es a veces